# TeamCity Inspections (IntelliJ IDEA) and Spring Data

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

TeamCity seems not to recognize Spring Data Repository beans when running the inspections. It works perfectly in IntelliJ IDEA but not in TeamCity.

I receive the following inspection problems:
Warning *This custom Spring bean has not yet been parsed* And it points to this XML element:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="my.base.package" />
```

And then (obviously) an Error: *Could not autowire. No beans of 'MyRepository' type found.*

MyRepository extends the Spring Data CrudRepository interface.

As far as I understand, TeamCity launches an IntelliJ instance when running the inspections. Do I have to specify in some way which plugins (Spring Data) IntelliJ has to use when it's running the inspections?

I also tried multiple times to hit the check/reparse button in TeamCity...

Thanks for your help!